# Excel 2013 Conditional Formating NOT() operator does not seem to work

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm puzzled by the following. I must be doing something wrong but can't see what.

**This works**

```
=FIND(A$6,CONCATENATE($A$2,$B$2,$C$2,$D$2,$E$2,$F$2,$G$2,$H$2,$I$2,$J$2,$K$2,$L$2,$M$2))
```

**This doesn't work**

```
=NOT(FIND(A$6,CONCATENATE($A$2,$B$2,$C$2,$D$2,$E$2,$F$2,$G$2,$H$2,$I$2,$J$2,$K$2,$L$2,$M$2)))
```

Everything is the same, the same range, the only difference is the NOT() operator that should change the condition from TRUE to FALSE and highlight the cells where the result of FIND() in not TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

`FIND` function doesn't return `TRUE` or `FALSE` - it returns the position of the search value (a number) or `#VALUE!` error if the search value isn't present

It works as required in conditional formatting because any non zero numerical result is the equivalent of `TRUE` (and zero is `FALSE`)

Arguably it would be more understandable to use this version to return `TRUE` in conditional formatting if the search value is found:

`=ISNUMBER(FIND(A$6,CONCATENATE($A$2,$B$2,$C$2,$D$2,$E$2,$F$2,$G$2,$H$2,$I$2,$J$2,$K$2,$L$2,$M$2)))`

So for the reverse, you can use `ISERROR` function, i.e.

`=ISERROR(FIND(A$6,CONCATENATE($A$2,$B$2,$C$2,$D$2,$E$2,$F$2,$G$2,$H$2,$I$2,$J$2,$K$2,$L$2,$M$2)))`

Note: If you expect the value `A6` to be equal to one of the `A2:M2` values it might be easier to use `COUNTIF` for this, e.g.

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$M$2,A$6)>0`

and

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$M$2,A$6)=0`

Comment: Thank you very much Barry, such a silly mistake on my part. And thank you for COUNTIF() much better solution, mine would not highlight cells like Test and Test2 when looking up from Test as it would find it in Test2.